# How to add reference of c++ dll (build with pure MSIL option) in silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have tried adding reference after converting it to .sl.dll, it gets added but my application shows blank page instead of the contents. How can I use the cpp code in silverlight? Also can we use unmanaged code via the managed one similar to WPF? Please note I am already using 2.0.5.0 version of system.dll.

Answer (score 1):

An application needs **full trust** in order to make use of unsafe code.  Even a [trusted Silverlight application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28VS.95%29.aspx) does not run with full trust, but a somewhat more relaxed set of permissions called "elevated trust".  I think you'll have to use WPF.

See the MSDN page on [pure and verifiable code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85344whh.aspx) for more details.  To be usable with less than full trust, an assembly has to be verifiable, and this poses significant restrictions on what that code can contain.

Comment: I need to use silverlight. Can I use a c++ library if it is build with pure MSIL option?

Comment: You can use a C++ library built with `/clr:safe`, which requires that it not make use of any unmanaged functionality such as pointers or DLL calls.