# Can we Add Refernce of C/C++ dll in Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Can we Add Reference of C/C++ dll in Silverlight Application.
I am using Silverlight 4.

Thanks.

Comment: @Denis : Are there any other options available ?

Comment: SL5 will have P/Invoke support for trusted apps. SL5 Beta should be out soon. Or you could try to wrap your dll in COM aoutomation object, that would alow you to call it from trusted OOB app in

Answer (score 0):

Answered by [Jeffrey Hantin:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223250/how-to-add-reference-of-c-dll-build-with-pure-msil-option-in-silverlight-appl)

> An application needs **full trust** in
>   order to make use of unsafe code. 
>   Even a trusted
>   Silverlight application does not
>   run with full trust, but a somewhat
>   more relaxed set of permissions called
>   "elevated trust".  I think you'll have
>   to use WPF.
>
> See the MSDN page on pure
>   and verifiable code for more
>   details.  To be usable with less than
>   full trust, an assembly has to be
>   verifiable, and this poses significant
>   restrictions on what that code can
>   contain.